# Covariance of Gamma Transformations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, variance, covariance

If I have two independent random variables: $X$ is governed by Gamma$(a,b)$ and $Y$ is governed by Gamma$(c,b)$, then how can I find the Cov($Z,X$), where $Z = X/Y$?

I tried using properties of covariance, but the transformation was messing me up.
Cov(Z,X) = E(ZX) - E(X)E(Z)

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}(Z,\,X)&=E[ZX]-E[Z]E[X]\\&=E[X^2/Y]-E[X/Y]E[X]\\&=E[X^2]E[1/Y]-E[X]^2E[1/Y]\\&=\operatorname{Var}(X)E[1/Y].\end{align}$$I leave it to you to write the final expression in terms of $a,\,b,\,c$.

Comment: =$\frac{a}{b^2}  \cdot \frac{b}{c-1} = \frac{a}{b(c-1)} $

Answer (score 0):

Also note that $\mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{1}{Y}\Big]$ is known as $\frac{1}{Y}\sim \text{Inverse Gamma}$

---

[Inverse Gamma Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution)